# Solr, filter with priority

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I need to filter documents by two fields **name** and **address**.
I need to get results with names contains 'mar' first and then results with addresses contains 'mar'. But I'm getting randomly filtered results.
Like:

```
(name:(mar))^20 OR address:(mar)
```

Results from this query all documents are randomly sorted.
If some type of **sorting** exists, I'll appreciate your help. Thanks.

EDIT:
Boost in query working, and problem not with boost but with sorting. I have third field **priority** and when I provide additional fq **priority asc** boosting don't affect result.

Comment: so you want to sort them by what?

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I've understood my mistake.
I need results with names contains 'mar' as first and then with addresses contains 'mar', and after it I needed just to order by priority asc, and after it order by **score desc** to get correct results. Now i just need to implement it with Django Haystack.